# Cannot start server on fresh Django Heroku setup

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, foreman

I am attempting to follow this django heroku setup documentation... but I am running into some problems when trying to start foreman.

***(Note, I am running windows 7)***

**Steps I am following (in git bash):**

Crete virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

Set it as active:

```
$ source venv/Scripts/activate
```

Install postgresql (doing this seperate from django-toolbelt since I don't have visual studio... I'm following this method http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

```
easy_install psycopg2-2.5.3.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.3.4-release.exe
```

Install django-toolbelt:

```
$ pip install django-toolbelt
```

Everything successfully installs. I start the project:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
```

Create a Procfile in the root with the following:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

Finally, I try to start foreman:

```
$ foreman start
```

**And I get the following error:**

```
13:33:48 web.1  | started with pid 4712
13:33:48 web.1  | exited with code 1
13:33:48 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
13:33:48        | Traceback (most recent call last):
(venv)
```

Comment: try to run the server with python manage.py runserver 8080 and check if you get any error. You can use the test server for debug the app.

Comment: Yes, I can run the built in development server... Is that acceptable for developing on my local environment before committing to Heroku?

Comment: Yep totally, it is very helpful because in debug mode, you can debug better than using gunicorn server. Ok then you ran your built in server and everything its ok ?

Comment: Yes I was able to deploy to heroku without problems. Thank you!

Comment: Ok the error is when you try to deploy locally?

Comment: The issue is that I cannot run the foreman server as instructed in the Heroku documentation. If it is okay to just use the built in django development server I will do that.